# Regarding FIND Instruction using Batch File. Storing result in a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am searching a string on a list of files under many subfolders. If the string is found, then i'll perform more statements (which is not important anyways on my question).

So what I did is use the FIND instruction, using /c option. Then store the result of the FIND trimming the right most last character (which is the number of occurence of the string on a file). See below for the sample code...

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('find /c "PROGRAM-ID." "C:\FORTEST\CBL001.cbl"') do SET findstr=%%A
SET findstr=%findstr:~-1%
echo %findstr%
```

That code above gives me

```
1
```

Which is correct because the word "PROGRAM-ID" only occurred once in CBL001.cbl..

Now if I implement this code on a for loop to check for all files within a folder...

```
for /r "C:\FORTEST\" %%G in (*.*) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('find /c "PROGRAM-ID." %%G') do SET findstr1=%%A
    SET findstr1=%findstr1:~-1%        
    echo %findstr1%
)
```

The echo is returning

```
ECHO is off.
```

I dont understand how inserting the for loop into another for loop would mess up the code....

Thanks for reading.

=======

EDIT: Problem solved. Thanks to @npocmaka

So originally, before all this fiasco regarding storing FIND result into variable, I was using ERRORLEVEL to determine if the FIND instruction found the string or not (which sounds much simpler), but the ERRORLEVEL is not returning the correct value even if the string was not found. Hence my current solution of storing the result of FIND and using that data for comparison.

But it seems DelayedExpansion was the original culprit causing ERRORLEVEL to not produce the correct value.

See below for final code.

```
for /r "C:\FORTEST" %%G in (*.*) do (
    find "PROGRAM-ID." %%G
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        echo ITS A COBOL
        ::do something
    ) else (
        echo NOPE NOT A COBOL
    )
)
```

Also thanks to other replies, tho I didnt bother using them, but I appreciate the efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is using [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Thanks to @npocmaka

Answer (score 0):

`find` doesn't write the dashes and filenames, if it gets it's input from a pipe. And there is no need for an additional variable (`findstr1`):

```
for %%G in (*.*) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('type %%G^|find /c "PROGRAM-ID."') do echo %%A %%G
)
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat detail to take note of. Thank you! As for the original problem, it was solved. I have edited my original post regarding the details. Thank you for your time!